# positive measure of subsets of [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need your assistance in proving the following lemma.

Let $E\subset [0,2]$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure. Then $A =  \{x \in [0,1] : 2x \in E\}$ has positive measure.

A sketch of my idea on its proof.

To prove the lemma, it suffices to show that its contrapositive is true.

Suppose $m(A) = 0$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists a collection of open intervals $\{I_k\}_k^\infty$ such that $A \subset\cup_k^\infty I_k$ and $\sum_k^\infty m(I_k)< \epsilon$.

My challenge is on how to extend this cover of $D$ to a cover of the set $E$.

I was thinking about setting $I_k^\prime = I_k \cup I_k+a$ for some constant $a$. My concern is on how to choose $a$ so that ${I_k^\prime}$ will be a cover of $E$ by open intervals.

Can anybody help me with a suitable $a$ or an alternative way to prove the lemma?

Comment: Don't you have just $m(A)= \frac{1}{2} m(E) > 0$ ?

Comment: @AlexL, the issue is we don't know for a fact that $E = 2A$. We just know that $2A\subset E$.

Comment: I think AlexL is right. Write that $\mu(E)=\int_{[0,2]} 1_E(x) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)$, where $1_E$ is the caracteristic function of $E$. And then do the substitution $y=x/2$. You get $\mu(E)=\int_{[0,1]} 1_E(2y) \times 2 \mathrm{d}\mu(y)$, i.e. $\mu(E)=2\int_{[0,1]} 1_A(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(y) = 2 \mu(A)$.

Comment: Sure $E=2A$ : $2A \subset E$ is clear, and conversely, if $y \in E$, then $y/2 \in [0,1]$ and $y=2(y/2) \in E$, so $y/2 \in A$ and then $y \in 2A$.

Comment: For any $S\subset \Bbb R$ let $S\cdot 2=\{2y:y\in S\}$. ...If $J $ is a family of open intervals with $\cup J\supset  A,$ then $J^*=\{ j\cdot 2: j\in J\}$ is a family of open intervals with $\cup J^*\supset E$ because $E=A\cdot 2.$ Therefore $\sum_{j\in J}m(j)=$ $\sum_{j\in J}m(j\cdot 2)/2=$ 
 $(\sum_{j^* \in J^*}m(j^*)\,)/2\geq$ $ m(E)/2$.